# Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring , Please can anyone help to resolve this exception.

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityDAO' defined in class path resource [springapp-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'configDetails' while setting bean property 'configDetails'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configDetails' defined in class path resource [springapp-servlet.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.taphius.databridge.deserializer.DataSourcerConfigDetails]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder
```

This is my main class

```
public class MainApp {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class);
    public static String FLUME_CONF_DIR = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springapp-servlet.xml");
        logger.info("Application context loaded successfully.");
    }

}
```

springapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd">

    <!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->

    <task:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="entityDAO" class="com.taphius.databridge.dao.EntityDefinationDAO">
        <property name="configDetails" ref="configDetails" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="configDetails"
        class="com.taphius.databridge.deserializer.DataSourcerConfigDetails">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value type="java.lang.Class">com.taphius.databridge.model.DataSourcerAttributes
            </value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataChecker" class="com.taphius.datachecker.FileChecker"
        init-method="init">
        <property name="entityDAO" ref="entityDAO" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="notifyChecker" class="com.taphius.pipeline.notification.PipelineNotifyWatcher"
        init-method="init">
        <property name="dataChecker" ref="dataChecker" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduledJob" class="com.taphius.databridge.scheduler.ScheduledDBPoller">
        <property name="task" ref="task" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="task" class="com.taphius.databridge.scheduler.CustomTask">
        <property name="entity" ref="entityDAO" />
        <property name="dataChecker" ref="dataChecker" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="runMeJob"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">

        <property name="jobClass"
            value="com.taphius.databridge.scheduler.ScheduledDBPoller" />

        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="task" value-ref="task" />
            </map>
        </property>
                <property name="durability" value="true"></property>

    </bean>
    <!-- Cron Trigger, run every 5 minutes -->

    <bean id="cronTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">

        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/2 * * * ?" />

    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="runMeJob" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 4):

You misss the jar containing class `com/google/gson/GsonBuilder` in your classpath. Add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have added this dependency, but still its the same.

Comment: @ChaitraBannihatti Have you cleaned and rebuild your application, and you are sure that is excactly the same class which is not found?